# HSQLDB - Is it possible to read property values?

Tags: java, hsqldb, rdbms

HSQLDB is highly configurable, allowing to set properties like this:

```
SET SESSION RESULT MEMORY ROWS <integer>
```

I would like to know if it is also possible to retrieve the current values.
I don't mind using Java code if this isn't possible via SQL.

Comment: Did you try `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES`?

Comment: I just did and indeed the properties seem to be stored there, if you make the comment an answer I will accept it. However these seem to be session properties and I wonder where should I look for database properties. Continuing with the original example another property of this kind would be the one set with `SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS <unsigned integer literal>`.

Comment: Session settings are reported with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_SESSIONINFO` but the `RESULT MEMORY ROWS` is not reported there. You can write a Java function to get it from the current session and create an SQL function based on it.